# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\res\connection.php on line 12

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need some help here. I have some code below, and my question is, I'm not getting where the error is, which is showing by the error message.

```
try
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; db_name=softdemo','root', '');
}   
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

try{
    foreach ( $db->query("SELECT * FROM users") as row )
    {
        echo $row['username'].$row['password']."<br/>";
    }
    $db = null;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();      
}
```

Comment: `row` would be `$row`!!

Comment: These kinds of errors should be solved with speicalized IDEs like PHPStorm, Eclipse or NetBeans. These are very common and should not be asked here. Solving these errors on the own improves debugging capability.

Comment: thnx for ur argument... :)

Answer (score 1):

Error comes from this line you missed `$` before $row variable

```
  foreach ( $db->query("SELECT * FROM users") as row )
```

Change this to

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
if(!empty($res))
{
  foreach( $res as $row )
  { //code here..
  }
}
```

Comment: Fixed it. but now its showing this warning message Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\res\connection.php on line 12

Comment: may be your query not giving any result.

Comment: store in variable then $var = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");pass in foreach

Comment: i have updated the answer please check.

Comment: thnx @VishnuSharma :)

Answer (score 1):

You've missed `$` sign, this is required as `$row` is a variable.

So, Change

```
foreach ( $db->query("SELECT * FROM users") as row )
```

To

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
if(!empty($res))
{
  foreach( $res as $row )
  { //code here..
  }
}
```

Comment: Fixed it. but now its showing this warning message

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\res\connection.php on line 12

Comment: i  have updated the code please check.

Comment: If this answer works for you, mark this as answer. It might help other users in future.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed out a `$`, this is required as `$row` is a variable.

```
foreach ( $db->query("SELECT * FROM users") as $row )
```